# Error: Specified cast is not valid. Xaml

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xaml, which has a grid with listview and button, and at the
moment of compiling this error appears:
Error: Specified cast is not valid.

I think the problem may be in the listview that is inside the grid, but I have not really been able to find a solution

this is my xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="FCR.App.Views.AdvanceSearchResultPage" Title="AdvanceSearchResultPage" xmlns:extended="clr-namespace:FCR.App.ExtendedClasses;assembly=FCR.App">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0, 10, 0, 0" WinPhone="20,20,20,20" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <ContentView IsVisible="false" x:Name="TitleHC">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="9.5*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="blue_circle.png" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <StackLayout Padding="0,4,0,5" VerticalOptions="Fill" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Label VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="#0368b1" Text="Histórico de conéxiones" FontSize="20">
                            <Label.FontFamily>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                    <OnPlatform.iOS>FrutigerLTStd-Cn</OnPlatform.iOS>
                                    <OnPlatform.Android>FrutigerLTStd-Cn.otf#FrutigerLTStd-Cn</OnPlatform.Android>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Label.FontFamily>
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ContentView>
            <ContentView IsVisible="false" x:Name="TitleHM">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="9.5*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="blue_circle.png" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <StackLayout Padding="0,4,0,5" VerticalOptions="Fill" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Label VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="#0368b1" Text="Histórico de módificaciones" FontSize="20">
                            <Label.FontFamily>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                    <OnPlatform.iOS>FrutigerLTStd-Cn</OnPlatform.iOS>
                                    <OnPlatform.Android>FrutigerLTStd-Cn.otf#FrutigerLTStd-Cn</OnPlatform.Android>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Label.FontFamily>
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ContentView>
            <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ContentView x:Name="contentListView" IsVisible="true" Padding="0,10,0,0" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="0">
                    <ListView x:Name="resultListView" BackgroundColor="White" HasUnevenRows="true" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Padding="0" Opacity="90">
                                            <ContentView Padding="1,0,1,1" BackgroundColor="Gray">
                                                <Grid
                                                    BackgroundColor="White">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*">
                                                        </ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*">
                                                        </ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*">
                                                        </ColumnDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                                                        <Label Margin="-5" Text="{Binding NombreCompleto}" TextColor="Gray" Font="Bold,13" />
                                                        <Label Margin="-5"
                                                            Text="{Binding OrganizacionMayusculas}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="13" />
                                                        <Label Margin="-5" Text="{Binding Region}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="13" />
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <Label Margin="0,0,0,2" Text="Detalle" Grid.Column="1"
                                                        Font="Bold, 13" ClassId="{Binding IdContacto}" TextColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="End">
                                                        <Label.FontFamily>
                                                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="8">
                                                                <OnPlatform.iOS>FrutigerLTStd-BoldCn</OnPlatform.iOS>
                                                                <OnPlatform.Android>FrutigerLTStd-BoldCn.otf#FrutigerLTStd-BoldCn</OnPlatform.Android>
                                                            </OnPlatform>
                                                        </Label.FontFamily>
                                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerDetail" />
                                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    </Label>
                                                    <Label Margin="0,0,0,2" Text="Borrar" Grid.Column="2"
                                                        Font="Bold, 13" ClassId="{Binding IdContacto}" TextColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="End">
                                                        <Label.FontFamily>
                                                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="8">
                                                                <OnPlatform.iOS>FrutigerLTStd-BoldCn</OnPlatform.iOS>
                                                                <OnPlatform.Android>FrutigerLTStd-BoldCn.otf#FrutigerLTStd-BoldCn</OnPlatform.Android>
                                                            </OnPlatform>
                                                        </Label.FontFamily>
                                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerDelete" />
                                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    </Label>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ContentView>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </ContentView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <extended:CustomButton Text="Volver" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dismissbutton" Clicked="OnDismissButtonClicked" WidthRequest="100" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Does the message say anything more? It usually says a cast from what to what is trying to be done. It's hard to say based on only this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The problem*

1. Generally these sort of error you might find while working with data binding. While we are trying to bind a different type with some controls which the complier is not exactly expecting.

There are few places I could find the binding little odd - 
`ClassId="{Binding IdContacto}"`

I am not sure whether you are binding correctly or not. If I were you I would have removed all the `ClassId` bindings and then go ahead with build compiling the process.

2. Also I would try to comment out the `OnPlatform` code and build/compile/Run the project.

These are some long shots which you may try. After looking at the whole Stacktrace may be we will be able to diagnose more towards the exact issue.